# Same Value Being Assigned to All Elements in List of Lists of Rectangles

Tags: c#, list, initialization, rectangles

I am new at C#, so please bear with me.

I need to use a List of Lists or Rectangles.
My problem is that whenever I set the value for one element, other elements are also being set.

For instance, if my List of Lists is "m_aRectWBLD ", of size 2 x 4,
When I set "m_aRectWBLD [0][0]", "m_aRectWBLD [1][0]" is also being set.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.
Here is the relevant code.

```
    private List<List<Rectangle>> m_aRectWBLD = new List<List<Rectangle>>();
    static readonly Rectangle m_Rectdef = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

    private void ResetAllData()
    {
        List<Rectangle> aRectZero = new List<Rectangle>();

        for (int i = 0; i != 4; i++)
            aRectZero.Add(m_Rectdef);

        m_aRectWBLD.Clear();                

        for (int i = 0; i != 2; i++)
        {
            m_aRectWBLD.Add(aRectZero);
        }

        m_aRectWBLD[0][0] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);    // after doing this both
                                                              // m_aRectWBLD[0][0] and
                                                              // m_aRectWBLD[1][0]
                                                              // have the same Rectangle value

    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you declare your `m_Rectdef` as `static readonly`?

Comment: Looks like Rectangle is a reference type and you are adding the same instance of rectangle to every list element - if it were a struct this might work, but it's not, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Charleh Yes, and that's the answer. Post it as an answer.

Comment: No thanks, I'd rather it not be a duplicate on SO - maybe if the OP can clarify their intent we can give them a push in the right direction

Comment: Hello, thank you for your replies.
What I was trying to do is to initialize the List of Lists of Rectangles with the default Rectangle value (0,0,0,0). And then, at some point during the program, each Rectangle would get updated.
I come from a C++ background, so there I would've just use vectors.
Thanks for your comments, they were helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private List<Rectangle> generateRectList()
{
    var aRectZero = new List<Rectangle>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        aRectZero.Add(m_Rectdef);

    return aRectZero;
}

private void ResetAllData()
{        
    m_aRectWBLD.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        m_aRectWBLD.Add(generateRectList());
    }

    m_aRectWBLD[0][0] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

Your issue is that you were assigning the same `aRectZero` to two locations of `m_aRectWBLD`. C# is referential so it will *literally* put the same `List` contained at the same memory address into two different slots of `m_aRectWBLD`.

Your final assignment: `m_aRectWBLD[0][0] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);` is placing the new rectangle at position `0` in the list located at position `0` in `m_aRectWBLD`. These two point to exactly the same list:

```
m_aRectWBLD[0] // List x
m_aRectWBLD[1] // List x
```

What you need to do is create a **new** `List` for each position. The change I made creates a new, separate `List` for each slot. The lists may then be modified independently.

If you wish to convince yourself further, assign the same (non-`readonly`) `Rectangle` to two positions of the list and try to modify one. It will modify the other.

### Additional points:

- It's more common to use a less than / greater than predicate in a for loop (prefer i > x not i != x)
- m_VARNAME is less common in C#, prefer lowercase starting CamelCase local/private variables/functions.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is exactly the type of answer I was hoping for. The problem is solved now. Thanks also for the style-related advice.